# Php user defined functions, (im new need help)

Tags: php, user-defined-functions

I understand I can define a function like this:

```
<?php 
    function say_hello() {
        echo "hello world!";
    }

    say_hello();
?>
```

...and then reuse this function elsewhere as many times as I need by just calling the function by name.

What I don't understand is "passing data to arguments *within* the function". I'm confused what's meant by *within*.

From one of the lessons I've been studying, I have this function:

```
<?php 
   function say_helloTWO( $word ) {
       echo " {$word} hello world a second time ";
   }

   say_helloTWO( "my name is mike");
?>
```

This prints on screen

> my name is mike hello world a second time

When I test the function with the argument `"my name is mike"`, it prints to screen, but I don't understand *how* this works. The variable `$word` wasn't declared anywhere, so, if I take out the `"$word"` from the echo, then only `"hello world a second time`" shows without the `my name is mike`.

This leads me to believe that somewhere within this block of code, `$word` was defined, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second function `$word` is being declared in the function definition `function say_helloTWO( $word )`.

So the function is expecting 1 parameter, which will be assigned to the variable `$word` for use *within* that function.

So when you call `say_helloTWO( "my name is mike");` you are passing 1 parameter ("my name is mike") to the function `say_helloTWO`. This 1 parameter gets assigned to the 1st variable in the function definition, and is therefore available within the function as `$word`.

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

In this case the function definition is said to take one arguments.

```
function say_helloTWO( $word ) // $word is the name of this argument
```

When you call the function in your code the first thing you pass in the brackets will be passed as the first argument. Therefore in your example the string `"my name is mike"` is being passed into the function and assigned to the variable $word.

If we expand on this and have a function that takes two arguments like this

```
function say_helloTHREE( $word, $secondArg )
```

Then this function would now expect two arguments to be passed into it. The first argument would be assigned to $word and the second argument will be assigned to $secondArg.

Answer (score 1):

This counts as a valid declaration. It's defined when supplied as an argument when the function is called.

```
<?php
    function my_name_is ($name) {
        echo "Hello, my name is " . $name;
    }
    my_name_is('mike');
    // returns 'Hello, my name is mike'
?>
```

Because, when calling the function, they supply 'mike' as an argument, $name becomes 'mike'. It's just how functions work.

EDIT:

It's a special rule. $name doesn't need to be declared because it will be defined when the function is called. PHP understands this. If you don't supply an argument, it's still defined, it's just empty... I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read this: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
   function say_helloTWO( $word ) {
       echo " {$word} hello world a second time ";
   }

   say_helloTWO( "my name is mike");
?>
```

In this code, the 'declaration' of the variable `$word` is made within the function declaration. As you see on this line `function say_helloTWO( $word ) {` you can find `$word` on that line. This is enough for the PHP parser to know that for the first agument of the is to be known as word within this functions scope. The function then echos out that variable on a later line `echo " {$word} hello world a second time ";` where again `$word` is present prints out both what you set as the value of the first argument on this line `say_helloTWO( "my name is mike");`.

Good question.

Comment: i do have one overall question to something small im not clear on. So according to this, in this particular manner, since $word equals "my name is mike" inside that function block,  is it a temporary var that got set in that functions declaration and if so, then does it mean that say, further down the page, that var2 wont have the same value? or is it available anywhere on that page?

Comment: It's only available within the scope of the function call. So that means that `$word` is only defined within the function's curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It's passed as a parameter. So it was sorta already declared inside the parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

If you did:

`function say_helloTWO( $word1, $word2, $word3 )`

and called:

`say_helloTWO("a", "b", "c");`

That would call `say_helloTWO` and set the variable `$word1` to `"a"`, `$word2` to `"b"` and `$word3` to `"c"`

Those three variables are defined in `say_helloTWO` for the duration that that function is running.

To give a practical example, say you had a function to solve quadratic equations, it would look like

```
function quadratic( $a, $b, $c ) { 
    $x = ( $b + sqrt( (b*b - 4*a*c) ) )/ 2*a;
    return $x;
}
```

Then, instead of rewriting the code to solve a quadratic each time, you could call it like this:

```
$y = quadratic (1, 2, 3);
```

This would set $a to 1, $b to 2 and $c to 3, and store the result in $y.

You can consider the quadratic function to be a sort of "mini-program", independent of the rest of your program, $a, $b and $c only apply within the `quadratic` function.

Answer (score 0):

> this leads me to believe that somewhere within this block of code, $word was defined, is that right?

No, $word is not defined within the function block, it is given the value of "my name is mike" when you mane the call.

In other words, $word is defined when you call the function:

```
/* here you are defining word to "my name is mike" */
say_helloTWO( "my name is mike");

/* here you are defining word to "my name is jack"*/
say_helloTWO( "my name is jack");
```

If the above still don't make much sense to you then I think you may need to go back to the basic and study what is a function in programming world.